# How can I install PySide2 or PyQt5 in Windows XP 32 bits?

Tags: python, pip, pyqt5, windows-xp, pyside2

I have latest version `Python 3.4.3`, compatible with Windows XP
32 bits. When I want to install `PySide2` or `Qt` I see:

> C:\Python34\Scripts>pip install PySide2 ERROR: Could not find a
>   version that satisfies the requirement PySide2 (from ver sions: none)
>   ERROR: No matching distribution found for PySide2

or

> C:\Python34\Scripts>pip install pyqt5 Collecting pyqt5   Downloading
>   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f0/3a/8f2261c0477008057636
>   b9f992952033748b9ee94541dd54373f7d6bf5f1/PyQt5-5.8-5.8.0-cp34.cp35.cp36.cp37-non
>   e-win32.whl (62.8MB)
>        |████████████████████████████████| 62.8MB 12kB/s ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement sip>=4.19.1 (from 
>   pyqt5) (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found for
>   sip>=4.19.1 (from pyqt5)

Comment: Both projects provide wheels for Python 3.5, 3.6 and 3.7, not 3.4. Python 3.4 is too old now.

Comment: You can have `Python3.4` with `PySide` which is for `Qt4`. Not `PySide2`. But it is not easy to configure anyway, because XP is very old. I put a lot of effort to make it work. Wheels are no more online, redistributable packets are no more online...

Answer (score 1):

I installed it and it works.
First https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/files/PyQt5/PyQt-5.5.1/
Second https://download.qt.io/official_releases/pyside/PySide-1.2.2.win32-py3.4.exe
(from https://download.qt.io/official_releases/pyside/)